# What's the difference between java JRE tarball and EXE

Tags: java

I'm getting confused about what package to use in order to install JAVA JRE on a Windows server machine.

Is there any difference between the tarball **jre-8u201-windows-x64.tar.gz** and **jre-8u201-windows-x64.exe**

Is there any more tools available in one or another, and which is recommended to use and why ?

Or both are the same, just the installation process that change.

Answer (score 1):

The tar has raw files.

The exe has additionally an installer.

At your current level choose the EXE.